# How to edit variable Odoo

Tags: python, automation, odoo, odoo-12

When a user orders a subscription we want to update their price list.

The ID of the current price list of the user that ordered a subscription is this:

```
env['res.partner'].search([['id', '=', record.partner_id.id]]).property_product_pricelist.id
```

But I now want to change that pricelist, how do I change the ID value?
Should I update any other values like the name or is it changed automatically?

Comment: `self.env[modol_name]` can link to db, and attach `.search([domain])`can find record you want. please give more info so that can give more specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I needed was this line:

```
env['res.partner'].search([['id', '=', record.partner_id.id]]).write({'property_product_pricelist': my_pricelist_id})
```

Comment: If you just want see another user's data replace ` record.partner_id.id` with the id you want. If you want to update info of `property_product_pricelist`. you need to update `my_pricelist_id`.